# Rails simple_form label above input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, input, label, simple-form

Using simple_form -- is there a way to change where the input field's label is placed?  If for example, I wanted to place the label above the field, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CSS styles for the label and/or input, add `display: block;`.

Comment: This will render the label below the checkbox and not above it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will render the label below the checkbox, not above it. If you want to position the label above (or to the left), you can explicitly add it with `f.label`:

**label above:**

```
simple_form_for my_model do |f|
f.label :my_boolean_field
f.input :my_boolean_field, style: 'display: block;'
```

**label to the left:**

```
simple_form_for my_model do |f|
f.label :my_boolean_field
f.input :my_boolean_field
```

---

---

When you don't include an explicit `label`, it will appear to the right of the checkbox or below it:

**label below:**

```
simple_form_for my_model do |f|
f.input :my_boolean_field, style: 'display: block;'
```

**label to the right** (why is this the default ):

```
simple_form_for my_model do |f|
f.input :my_boolean_field
```

<sub>*tested on rails 5.2.3, simple_form 4.1.0*</sub>